# Appropriate ways to convey "that's what friends are for"

Tags: translation

Example:

```
> A: Thanks a lot for helping me!
> B: Sure thing – that's what friends are for.
```

What are ways to convey "that's what friends are for"?

I wonder if there are different ways to express this that differ in connotation, for example:

- A casual, joking setting: "of course, we're friends!" "you'd do it for me too"
- A formal setting: "my pleasure: we are friends"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"That's what friends are for" may be translated as 친구는 그러라고 있는 거야, but this doesn't seem to be said much (the phrase doesn't sound so natural in Korean).

There doesn't seem to be one phrase but many different ones.

A: 도와줘서 고마워. (Thank you for helping me!)

B1: 고맙기는.  친구 사이인데.  (Thank me? We are friends, aren't we).
B2: 고맙긴.  친구가 왜 있는데. (Thank me? What are friends for?)
B3: 무슨 소리야.  친구면 당연히 도와야지. (What are you saying? Friend should help friend)
B4: 아니야. 친구인데 그것도 못 도와주겠어. (Don't say that. What friend wouldn't do such a small thing?)
B5: 아니야. 그 정도도 못하면 친구도 아니다. (Don't say that. Anyone who wouldn't do that much is not even a friend)

Comment: Thank you for the idiomatic answers!

Comment: "그래서 친구가 있는 거지" ("That's what friends are for") is idiomatic (personally the most preferred), too.